# Discord.js block a user from banning a person with a specific role

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying for some time now and I can't work out how to stop someone from banning a user with a specific role, I've stopped them from banning themselves but I can't work out how to do it for a role.

Here is my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, User } = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => { 
  let logs = await client.channels.fetch('993755247652634716')
  const target = args[0];
  if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('I don\'t have permission to ban members!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('You don\'t have permission to ban members!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
  if (isNaN(target)) return message.reply(`Please specify an ID`);
  if (target===message.author.id) message.reply('Why you want to ban yourself?!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } })  

  let member = client.members.cache.get(target);{
  if (member.roles.cache.has("950383380334260285")) message.reply("No banning trial mods please");}
     
  let reason = "No reason provided.";
  if (args[1]) reason = args.splice(1).join(" ");
    
  try {
    message.guild.members.ban(target, {reason: reason.length < 1 ? 'No reason supplied.': reason});            
    message.delete()    
  } catch (error) { console.log(error) }
}

module.exports.config = {
  name: "hackban",
  aliases: ['forceban', 'softban'],
  usage: "[hackban || forceban] <user ID>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `return` statement in your conditions.

```js
if (target === message.author.id) return message.reply('Why you want to ban yourself?!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });

if (member.roles.cache.has("950383380334260285")) return message.reply("No banning trial mods please");
```

The rest of the code is no longer executed after a `return` statement, exactly like you did in the permissions checker.